# When will the modified time of folder be changed？

Tags: filesystems, inode

When will the modified time of folder be changed, on both of windows and linux?
I know the modified time changed when its inode is changed.  But when will the inode of folder be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Windows and Linux differ on this; indeed, within both, this is largely dependent upon rules present within the filesystem format (NTFS, EXT4, XFS, and so on).

Microsoft give some details on how it works in NTFS [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299648).

For EXT, there are some details in the [ext wiki](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/).

Other filesystems will have this information in similar sources.